# Cannot use .query commands leaves to an error in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

**Problem:**

I have created a node application there I am adding admin to the database like this in userModal.js file.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var sql = require('../db.js');

module.exports.save_admin = (new_admin,callback) =>{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err, salt)=> {
        bcrypt.hash(new_admin.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
            new_admin.password = hash;
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            else{
                console.log(new_admin.password);
                sql.query("INSERT INTO administrators set ?", new_admin, callback);     
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is how I am calling this function from the controller.

```
var admin = {
          first_name: req.body.first_name,
          last_name: req.body.last_name,
          organization: req.body.organization,
          admin_level: req.body.admin_level,
          user_identity: req.body.identity,
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password
        };

        User.save_admin(admin, (err,user) => {
          if (!err) {
            res.json({ state: true, msg: "data Inserted" });
          } else {
            res.json({ state: false, msg: "data Is Not Inserted" });
          }
        });
```

This is how I have configured the database in db.js file.

```
'user strict';

var mysql = require('mysql');

//local mysql db connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'mydatabase'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (!err){
        console.log("Database connection succeeded...!");
    }

    else{
        console.log('Error in DB connection :'+JSON.stringify(err,undefined, 2));
    }
});

module.exports = connection;

module.exports = {
    "secret": "myapplicationsecret"
};
```

This setup leaves me this error.

> sql.query("INSERT INTO administrators set ?", new_admin, callback);
>                       ^
>
> TypeError: sql.query is not a function

Comment: looks at the last two lines of code, you're setting the connection to `module.exports` and in the following line you're overriding it.

Comment: Thank you. It works